# how to hide all fields by using a search with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to make a search by using jquery, I have an : 
 input text with this id `idTextSearch`:

```
<input id="idTextSearch" name="name" type="text" style="width:70%;"  >
```

input button with this id `idButtonSearch`:

```
<input id="idButtonSearch" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searching()" class="alt_btn">
```

and a `<ul class="toggle"  id="idUl">` with different `<li value="thisIsAValue">`

Now, I need to create my `searching()`, this function will hide all elements field different to `$("#idTextSearch").val()` and show only one field with the same value of this input text.

Comment: really not clear what you're trying to do. Consider providing a block of HTML (rather than little snippets) and describing what you want to happen. Would be useful for you to put an example up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Post your JS and we'll help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time, please post what you've tried to do to solve the problem. In this case I'll give you the answer because it's simple, but we're here to *help* you, not to *write all your code for you*.

Note that the `value` attribute technically doesn't exist on the `li` element, you should prefix it with `data`. Eg:

```
<li data-value="thisIsAValue">
```

And the javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#idButtonSearch').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#idUl li').hide().each(function() {
        if ( $(this).data('value') === $('#idTextSearch').val() ) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searching() {
    var val = $('#idTextSearch').val();
    $('#idUl li').each(function() {
        var v = $(this).prop('value');
        if(v == val) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```